# imperative for Be Quiet / Hush

Tags: tiempos-verbales, imperativo

What is the best informal imperative form for saying Be Quiet! or Hush! e.g. to a small child or pet?

A friend of mine said *¡Callado!* would work, not sure about that or *¡Cállate!* (which I guess means "shut up").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Calla* and *cállate*, as well as *(estate) callado* will work, meaning exactly *shut up* and *be quiet*.

Also *silencio*, and the shush *shhh*. And maybe *chitón*.

Any of these will work for adult the same as for children. I don't know of any words specifically for children.

Comment: Good answer. I would add "chisst" to that list, to _chistar_ somebody to be quiet.

Answer (score 2):

If you go for singular:

> Calla. Cállate.

as you suggested. If you go for plural:

> Callaos.

but I would not consider that informal. I'm unsure if culturally is considered less rude than in English to tell somebody to *shut up*. Also I think that many people use wrongly the imperative in Spanish (I mean, native Spanish Speakers), using the infinitive instead of imperative when referring to the plural (e.g. `vamos, comer`, instead of `vamos, comed`). I can confirm that your friend is wrong when suggesting `callado`. That is the participle and not the imperative. Would only work if you say

> Estate callado, por favor.

But the is *estar* what is in the imperative form.

To answer your question, for a kid I would use the `Estate callado, por favor` form (you want to teach them manners, after all). For a pet, I would probably go with just `chisst!!` or `calla`.

Comment: You don't have to be close-minded about language. "Callado" would work just fine, even if it isn't the actual imperative form. Also, suggesting a native speaks their own language incorrectly is a very bold claim (and normally can't be sustained)

Comment: I Strongly disagree on both things. I'm a native speaker and I would never use "callado". I would either use "estate callado" or "calla/cállate". I have never heard it being used as imperativo. Second, people make mistakes when they talk. I have heard many of those "patadas al diccionario" in both countries. I have heard some native speakers saying in English "He don't" for example. Trust me, I have heard people use infinitive to express a command many many times.

Comment: Is there a difference between countries? (Spain / Mexico / Caribbean / South America) My friend is Mexican-American and grew up at various times on both sides of the border.

Comment: @Diego No, I think you misunderstood my comment. I do believe you when you say people use the infinitive. I'm saying it's wrong to say that it's _incorrect_. The other answer here seems to suggest _callado_ is a possibility, and seems to be made a native.

Comment: @JasonS, I'm pretty confident that we use the _imperative_ the same way at both sides of the pond.

Comment: @clinch, I think that the tint with that answer is that the correct form is "**estate** callado".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be more polite you can also say:

> Guarda silencio por favor.

which would translate to

> Keep quiet please.

Answer (score 0):

"Callate" or "Callate la boca"  in Mexico are equal to "shut up" or "shut your mouth"in the US.
Calla is softer, more like "Hush!" or "Quiet!" in the US.